# Edit default views (books, basic page, etc)

Tags: views, nodes

I am using Views 3 with drupal 7. Views provide you some default views so you can edit them and customize them.

I want to do the same thing, for example, with book pages. I don't want to start from scratch with a new view. I just want to edit the default view of book pages.

Is there any way of editing it ? Or should I go directly to the code ? If so, which code is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit any existing view. Go to the views list and click on enable button that you would see on the view that you want to edit. Then you would get access to go inside the view and make your changes.

Hope that Helps.

Best Regards
Shameem

Comment: @Shameem Yes, but I don't have the "book page" views in the list

Comment: what is the kind of change that you want to make in the book page? if it is just styling and placement changes then you could do it with the template files.

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is to move the table of content at the beginning of the page for example. Also, I want to add display some fields I added to the book page. Thanks !

Comment: If the need is only to bring the links to the top then you could do that in the node template. The entire page content is printed in the links. So you can place the following some were in the top of the top file.

<div class="links"><?php print render($content['links']); ?></div>

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. In fact, this is just an example. What I want to do is to edit the default view used by drupal for book page but I don't find it.

Comment: as for the books drupal doesn't use views to display it as far as I know. It is just nodes with the links as mentioned.

Comment: Ok, so I have to edit directly the code for displaying the node "book". Can you tell me where is it in the drupal files ? Thanks

Comment: in your theme folder depending on the theme you are using you would have a file called node.tpl.php. this is for the entire nodes. you would want to do it for just the book type. so you would create a file called node-book.tpl.php and copy the contents of node.tpl.php. In that you would see a $content['link']) you can place the where ever you want the links to be displayed